# Bulk Exporting Data from Codeigniter to CSV using Database Utility Class

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, datatable, codeigniter-2

Here is my code:

```
function export_csv()
{
$st = $this->input->get('st');   //Start Date 
$en = $this->input->get('en');   //End Date

$sTable = 'TABLE_NAME';

$this->load->dbutil();

$aColumns = array('tempdisplayid AS ucid','uui','campaign_name','location','caller_id','skill','calltime','answertime','TIMEDIFF(answertime,calltime) as timetoanswer','endtime','talktime','duration','fallback_rule','dialed_number','type','agent','agent_did','disposition','status','hangup_by','transfer','transfer_to','comments','dial_status','customer_status','agent_status','audio','AgentStatus','CustomerStatus','user_response');

$this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '.str_replace(' , ', ' ', implode(', ', $aColumns)), false);

$query = $this->db->get_where($sTable, array('date(calltime) >=' =>$st,'date(calltime) <=' =>$en));

$new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);

write_file('/csv/records-'.$st.'to'.$en.'.csv', $new_report);

$this->load->helper('download'); 

force_download('records-'.$st.'to'.$en.'.csv', $new_report); 

}
```

There is 64,145 Records in last 30 days. When I try to download the link becomes dead.is there any other method to bulk export unlimited record to `csv`.

I tested this code upto 30000 after setting ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);It works fine.

Anything other than CSV like xls which can show bulk records.

Comment: try creating a zip file of your csv and than download.. you can use codeigniter's **encoding class** check it here  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html

Comment: @NishantSolanki - not working either

Comment: @kiran what you mean by dead link?? what error you get??

Comment: @NishantSolanki -  no error only blank white page

Comment: @Kiranarya have you tried limiting the data?? if thats working??

Comment: @NishantSolanki -  I tried upto 35000 records its working fine.but problem is have to give monthly report which consist more than 60000 records.Is there any method by which i can export it in parts.

Comment: are you on a shared sever??Forget codeigniter for a while, use this corePHP code... Try outputting the file directly on the browser.. Look at this link : **Point 3** ..http://docforge.com/wiki/PHP/CSV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80122/discussion-between-kiran-arya-and-nishant-solanki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// top of your controller
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

// Also you can increase memory
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```

Download this [helper](http://jeromejaglale.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=&cache=cache&media=php:csv_helper.zip) and place in `system/helpers/`

and finally create csv like this

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$query = $this->db->get('your_table');
$this->load->helper('csv');
query_to_csv($query, TRUE, 'filename.csv');
```

Comment: Upto 10 MB CSV with 24000 records my code is working fine but not more than that

Comment: Make a try with this, and let me know

Comment: dead link meaning ? try to increase memory as well

Comment: Dead link means nothing just white blank page

Comment: I increased max_execution_time and memory_limit both.but page is loading from last 4-5 minutes.I think it worked hopefully by the end of the this day i will get my CSV file

Comment: 64,145 rows are not big by the way, kiran you may be having some other problem I guess

Comment: sir  - i have written my code above.see if there is any problem

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in `max_execution_time` of codeignator

You can increase it by using below code

Go to the file

```
system/core/CodeIgniter.php
```

Ans search for `set_time_limit` you find below code. Here you can increse your time

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);// increase according to your requirmrnt
}
```

Comment: @set_time_limit(1000); @set_time_limit(10000); but still white blank page

Comment: 300 means 5 minutes.. check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php... and if dont want to timeout the page than one should use `set_time_limit(0);`..

Comment: Thanks @NishantSolanki for your link am bit confuse in second or minutes now it clear