# jquery datatable exporting large datasets

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables. I have enabled export feature, however the page seems to timeout if i try to export `39,000` rows in IE, within chrome it works sometimes. The size of the file is 33mb.

If I click in IE i get following message

`<domain> is not responding due to long-running script`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? how do I do this? and how does this help?

Comment: it's time limit problem,,,IE need longer time to process your request...you need to set the time limit higher..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460263/disabling-the-long-running-script-message-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Datatable export won't work you have to do it by query.

Comment: Browsers are designed to handle page sizes on *average* around 50kb.   And you wonder why it doesn't like 33Mb???

Comment: @Bugfixer any example code i can look at. Do I have to code it using PHPExcel?

Comment: @bonez - i had same issue.but this answer is for codeigniter (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724404/bulk-exporting-data-from-codeignitor-to-csv-using-database-utility-class)

Comment: @Bugfixer I don't use codeignitor. its a custom framework. if only IE supported jquery datatables export!!! works on chrome